# sending email using nodemailer from godaddy email

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

here is my code to integrate godaddy email using nodemailer

```
var transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({    
    service: 'Godaddy',
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",  
    secureConnection: true,
    port: 465,

    auth: {
        user: "***",
        pass: "***" 
    }
});
```

it gives error i have also tried using port 80 and `smtpout.asia.secureserver.net` it also does not work below is my godaddy gmail settings

```
Server  Standard                                 ports        SSl
Incoming server (IMAP):
imap.asia.secureserver.net                       143          993

Incoming server (POP3):                          
pop.asia.secureserver.net                        110          995

Outgoing server (SMTP):
smtpout.asia.secureserver.net                    80,3535,25   465
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work*. Do you have an error?

Comment: Try replace `secureConnection` by `secure`

Comment: it gives configuration error

Comment: if i use my gmail account configuration instead of this i am getting emails something is wrong with this configuration of godaddy email

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact `configuration error` it gives?

Comment: i am currently on production version i can give you whats on server logging Failed at the authentication@1.0.0 start script. process exited with status 1 state changed from starting to crashed

Comment: var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
         user: '**',
         pass: '**'
     }
 }); if i replace it with this all is working right

Answer (score 0):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Godaddy',
  host: 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
  secure: true,
  secureConnection: false, 
  tls: {
    ciphers: 'SSLv3',
  },
  requireTLS: true,
  port: 465,
  debug: true,
  auth: {
    user: xxx,
    pass: yyy,
  },
});
```